# Como determina quantas pessoas teria que receber centavos a mais em uma divisão

Tags: javascript

Boa noite pessoal, a estória e a seguinte:
uma comanda de valor de 100 reais, dividida por 3 pessoas ficaria 33.33333, utilizando o toFixed(2) e retorna 33,33(e um dos objetivos), porem quando faz a soma desses valores para confirmar fica neste exemplo faltando 1 centavo.

como poderia fazer para determinar quantas pessoas teria que receber os centavos a mais para a conta fechar.
Ex1: valor de 100/3  =  cliente1: 33.34, cliente2: 33.33 e cliente3: 33,00
Ex2: valor de 100/7 = cada cliente ficaria com 14.28 e somando esse valor fica 99.96(para onde foi os 4 centavos)

Obs.: já pesquisei, muito na verdade. Não obtive resposta que atendesse ao problema

Comment: que gente mão de vaca reclamado 1 centavo credo... deixa pro garçom! :D

Comment: as pessoas não vão receber os centavos que sobram por igual (isso se não for só 1 centavo), pq não joga tudo para um único cliente?

Comment: Entao ricardo, pensei nessa solução tambem, porem dependendo do valor e quantidade de divisor, esse valor de 1 centavo pode variar.

Comment: Pra conta fechar, alguém vai ter que pagar esses centavos a mais, nunca vai ser totalmente "justo". No caso de sobrar 4 centavos, vc decide se dá pra um só pagar tudo ou se distribui 1 centavo pra 4 "sortudos" (ou seja, 6 pessoas pagam 14.28 e uma paga 14.32, ou 3 pagam 14.28 e 4 pagam 14.29), ou qualquer outro critério que vc quiser (1 paga 1 centavo e outro paga 3, ou 2 pessoas pagam 2 centavos a mais, sei lá, vc tem que escolher um critério de distribuição dos centavos que sobram)

Comment: Adiciona um centavo para um dos 3 e pronto.

Answer (score 0):

Vê se eu entendi o problema:

Você tem uma quantia X que vai ser dividida entre 3 participantes.

Você precisa dividir igualmente entre os 3 participantes o toFixed(2)  de X/3 multiplicado por três.

Se for isso, você pega 100, subtrai pelo o que sobrou, e em seguida pega o resultado, divide por três 3, que vai dar uma quantia Z (quebrada). Daí você dá um valor Z para cada uma das três pessoas.

Como dividir 1 centavo entre três pessoas? Simples: Divide por três e dá 0.003333333333333 para cada uma delas.

Answer (score 0):

Faz com inteiros.

1. Multiplica o valor da conta por 100. No teu exemplo, que a conta é 100.00, ficaria com 10000. **Lembre de usar o valor como inteiro após multiplicar por 100.**
2. Pega o valor da `divisão inteira` do valor da conta pela quantidade de clientes. **No teu exemplo (10000 DIV 3), o resultado será 3333.**
3. Pega o resto da divisão inteira. **No teu exemplo (10000 MOD 3) vai ser 1**. Esse resto é a quantidade de pessoas que terá que pagar um centavo a mais que as demais. Suponha que este valor está na variável `RESTO`.
4. Escolha as `RESTO` pessoas que vão pagar a mais e adicione 1 para cada uma delas. **No teu exemplo, uma pessoa ficará com 3334 e as outras 2 ficarão com 3333.**
5. Divida o valor de cada uma delas por 100. **No teu exemplo: 33.33, 33.33 e 33.34.**

Se você olhar bem pro segundo exemplo: 100 reais pra 7 pessoas:

```
100 * 100   => 10000
10000 DIV 7 => 1428.... um vetor: [1428, 1428, 1428, 1428, 1428, 1428, 1428]
10000 MOD 7 => 4 ... escolha 4 sortudos pra pagar 1 centavo a mais que os outros

Supondo que você decidiu escolher os primeiros da fila:
[1429, 1429, 1429, 1429, 1428, 1428, 1428]
```